# How to calculate compile time, execution time ,performance and success measure of a test?

Tags: c++, time

I have c++ program in that i want to have compiletime, execution time ,performance measure and success measure of a test.Right now i am calculating time as follows:

```
clock_t starts = clock();
test_case();
clock_t ends = clock();
double time = (double)(ends - starts);
```

But i dont know wether "time" is compile time or execution time. If it is compile time then how will i get execution time or if it is execution time how will i get its compile time. Also, i need to have performance and success mesure of the "test_case()". So, suggest me how will i get it.

Comment: The `time` is a program execution time

Comment: The time you measure in the code is the CPU time of the running code. No statements you write will ever be able to measure compile-time, as they are not executed when compiling.

Comment: `time` is execution time, because it gets executed at run time. Take a look at [how to execute code at compile time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time_function_execution)

Comment: It always give you runtime clock. You should give a try on [std::clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) which is more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

The `time` that you are calculating is the execution time. `clock()` returns the number of clock ticks since your program started. Hence taking the difference of `starts` and `ends` will give you execution time of `test_case()` in second multiplied by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is the number of clock ticks per second.

Compile time calculation can be done using template metaprogramming.

To get a view template metaprogramming, have a look at: [Compile Time Calculation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Compile-time_calculation#C.2B.2B)

If you are using UNIX, you can easily get `compilation time` using command like:

```
time g++ file_name.cpp
```

This will output the time required by `g++ file_name.cpp` to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The above function outputs the execution time. I would prefer to use query performance counter for finding the execution time.

However, we can find the build time if we are using a VC++ compiler. 
The option can be found at Tools->Options->VC++ProjectSettings->BuildTime

Answer (score 0):

The `time` is execution time, because it get by the `ends` and `starts`.But the function `clock()` is not a good way for caculate codes' execution time, for its low accuracy(maybe ms).

I suggest you use c++  STL `chrono`, you will get more accurate output.Example:

```
    int main()
    {
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point begin_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
        {
            //do something
            ;
        }
        chrono:: high_resolution_clock::time_point stop_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        chrono::duration<double> slapsed = duration_cast<duration<double>>(stop_time - begin_time);
        cout << "time takes " << slapsed.count() * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: How do you know `clock()` has low accuracy? The OP never showed what `clock()` does.

Comment: @rozina: clock ( ) is from the old C library `time.h`, or `ctime` in C++. 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you :) Still the OP never showed he included time.h, so it is still an assumption :)

Comment: @rozina, you can write a test, if your codes takes for less than 1ms, you will  get 0 ms. So the clock() 's accurancy is about 1ms.

Comment: You missed the point. The OP's code does not have `#include <time.h>` written, so there is no way of knowing what his `clock()` function does.

Comment: @rozina, okay, if it is a pseudocode, I have not knew it well first.

Comment: @rozina: Since he uses `clock_t` datatype, and `clock ( )` function, then most people assume that he uses `ctime`, since these are defined in C standard library. And it's the most common way to measure time consumption in the C language, but here are we dealing with C++, and C++ has a more accurate way to measure time with example std::chrono.

Ofcourse he could have defined own `clock_t` and `clock ( )` but it would then be wierd not to attach the definition of these two to the post.